# Whats the best download method for vb?

Tags: vb.net, performance, ftp, download, client

I am trying to make a download client with ftp and im still trying to find out whats the best i have but im in stuck because i followed a guide but it only show how much its have downloaded in bytes, how can i change it to gb? and how can i add a download speed?

```
Imports System.Net
Public Class MainForm

Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
End Sub

Private Sub btnBrowseSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowseSave.Click
    Dim newFolder As New FolderBrowserDialog
    If newFolder.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        txtSavePath.Text = newFolder.SelectedPath
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnDownload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDownload.Click
    bWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub bWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bWorker.DoWork
    Dim buffer(1023) As Byte
    Dim bytesIn As Integer
    Dim totalBytesIn As Integer
    Dim output As IO.Stream
    Dim flLength As Integer
    Try
        Dim FTPRequest As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(txtFilePath.Text), FtpWebRequest)
        FTPRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(txtFTPUsername.Text, txtFTPPassword.Text)
        FTPRequest.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize
        flLength = CInt(FTPRequest.GetResponse.ContentLength)
        lblFileSize.Text = flLength & " bytes"
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Try
        Dim FTPRequest As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(txtFilePath.Text), FtpWebRequest)
        FTPRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(txtFTPUsername.Text, txtFTPPassword.Text)
        FTPRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
        Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = FTPRequest.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
        Dim OutputFilePath As String = txtSavePath.Text & "\" & IO.Path.GetFileName(txtFilePath.Text)
        output = System.IO.File.Create(OutputFilePath)
        bytesIn = 1
        Do Until bytesIn < 1
            bytesIn = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)
            If bytesIn > 0 Then
                output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesIn)
                totalBytesIn += bytesIn
                lblDownloadedBytes.Text = totalBytesIn.ToString & " bytes"
                If flLength > 0 Then
                    Dim perc As Integer = (totalBytesIn / flLength) * 100
                    bWorker.ReportProgress(perc)
                End If
            End If
        Loop
        output.Close()
        stream.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub bWorker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bWorker.ProgressChanged
    pBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    lblPercent.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString & "%"
End Sub

Private Sub bWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    MsgBox("Download Complete!")
End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

1 KB = 2<sup>10</sup> bytes =                                     1,024 bytes
1 MB = 2<sup>10</sup> KB = 2<sup>20</sup> bytes =               1,048,576 bytes
1 GB = 2<sup>10</sup> MB = 2<sup>30</sup> bytes =        1,073,741,824 bytes
1 TB = 2<sup>10</sup> GB = 2<sup>40</sup> bytes = 1,099,511,627,776 bytes

The next units are Petabytes PB and Exabytes EB (maybe in future computer generations?).

Here is a function that formats the byte numbers. It determines the appropriate unit automatically:

```
Public Function FormatBytes(ByVal bytes As Long) As String
    Dim sizes As String() = {"B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB"}
    Dim order As Integer = 0
    Dim len As Double = bytes
    While len >= 1024 AndAlso order + 1 < sizes.Length
        order += 1
        len = len / 1024
    End While
    Return String.Format("{0:0.0} {1}", len, sizes(order))
End Function
```

---

Initialize the worker with:

```
bWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
```

You can also pass the number of bytes instead of a percentage to the `ReportProgress` method. The BackgroundWorker doesn't care. Because big files might exceed `Integer.MaxValue` declare `totalBytesIn As Long` instead as of `Integer` and pass the progress in KB to the `ReportProgress` method:

```
bWorker.ReportProgress(CInt(totalBytesIn / 1024))
```

In the `ProgressChanged` event handler:

```
Private Sub bWorker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                    ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) _
    Handles bWorker.ProgressChanged

    Me.txtProgress.Text = FormatBytes(1024 * e.ProgressPercentage)
    ' More code to come here ... (see below)
End Sub
```

As for the speed you could use a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`. It shows you the elapsed time.

```
Dim stopwatch As New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
stopwatch.Start()
```

And then in `bWorker_ProgressChanged`:

```
Dim elapsedSeconds As Double = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000
If elapsedSeconds > 0 Then
    Dim speed As Double = bytes / elapsedSeconds
    lblSpeed.Text = FormatBytes(CInt(speed)) & " / s"
End If
```

The final version of the progress changed event handler:

```
Private Sub bWorker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) _
   Handles bWorker.ProgressChanged

    Dim bytes As Long = 1024 * e.ProgressPercentage

    'Can exceed 100% beacause of rounding effects
    Dim percent As Integer = Math.Min(100, CInt(100 * bytes \ flLength))

    pBar.Value = percent
    lblPercent.Text = percent & "%"
    lblDownloadedBytes.Text = FormatBytes(bytes)

    Dim elapsedSeconds As Double = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000
    If elapsedSeconds > 0 Then
        Dim speed As Double = bytes / elapsedSeconds
        lblSpeed.Text = FormatBytes(CInt(speed)) & " / s"
    End If
End Sub
```

And if you declare `flLength` in the Form instead as local variable, you can calculate and display the percentages in `bWorker_ProgressChanged` as well.

---

As you have troubles understanding my answer, here is the complete code. Where possible I kept your code as is and marked my changes with comments (`'===`). (I had only my code snippets from above until now, so I had to create a form with all the required controls. It's tested and it works):

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class MainForm

    Dim flLength As Long '=== As Form variable instead as local variable and As Long.
    Dim stopwatch As New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch() '=== New variable.


    Private Sub MainForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnBrowseSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowseSave.Click
        Dim newFolder As New FolderBrowserDialog
        If newFolder.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            txtSavePath.Text = newFolder.SelectedPath
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDownload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnDownload.Click
        bWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bWorker.DoWork
        Dim buffer(1023) As Byte
        Dim bytesIn As Integer
        Dim totalBytesIn As Long '=== As Long instead of Integer
        Dim output As IO.Stream
        'Dim flLength As Integer '=== Now as form variable
        Try
            Dim FTPRequest As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(txtFilePath.Text), FtpWebRequest)
            FTPRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(txtFTPUsername.Text, txtFTPPassword.Text)
            FTPRequest.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize
            flLength = CInt(FTPRequest.GetResponse.ContentLength)
            lblFileSize.Text = flLength & " bytes"
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Try
            stopwatch.Start() '=== Start Stopwatch

            Dim FTPRequest As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(txtFilePath.Text), FtpWebRequest)
            FTPRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(txtFTPUsername.Text, txtFTPPassword.Text)
            FTPRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
            Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = FTPRequest.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
            Dim OutputFilePath As String = txtSavePath.Text & "\" & IO.Path.GetFileName(txtFilePath.Text)
            output = System.IO.File.Create(OutputFilePath)
            bytesIn = 1
            Do Until bytesIn < 1
                bytesIn = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)
                If bytesIn > 0 Then
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesIn)
                    totalBytesIn += bytesIn
                    lblDownloadedBytes.Text = totalBytesIn.ToString & " bytes"
                    If flLength > 0 Then
                        '=== Moved to bWorker_ProgressChanged.
                        'Dim perc As Integer = (totalBytesIn / flLength) * 100

                        '=== Now reports downloaded bytes in KB instead of percent.
                        bWorker.ReportProgress(CInt(totalBytesIn / 1024))
                    End If
                End If
            Loop
            output.Close()
            stream.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    '=== Completely reworked
    Private Sub bWorker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
       ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) _
       Handles bWorker.ProgressChanged

        Dim bytes As Long = 1024 * e.ProgressPercentage

        'Can exceed 100% beacause of rounding effects
        Dim percent As Integer = Math.Min(100, CInt(100 * bytes \ flLength))

        pBar.Value = percent
        lblPercent.Text = percent & "%"
        lblDownloadedBytes.Text = FormatBytes(bytes)

        Dim elapsedSeconds As Double = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000
        If elapsedSeconds > 0 Then
            Dim speed As Double = bytes / elapsedSeconds
            lblSpeed.Text = FormatBytes(CInt(speed)) & " / s"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub bWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
        MsgBox("Download Complete!")
    End Sub

    '=== New Function
    Private Function FormatBytes(ByVal bytes As Long) As String
        Dim sizes As String() = {"B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB"}
        Dim order As Integer = 0
        Dim len As Double = bytes
        While len >= 1024 AndAlso order + 1 < sizes.Length
            order += 1
            len = len / 1024
        End While
        Return String.Format("{0:0.0} {1}", len, sizes(order))
    End Function
End Class
```

See: [How to: Use a Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: so i shoud just change the bytesIn = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024) with bytesIn = stream.Read(buffer, 0,  1048576)??

Comment: hi Oliver its a great help you made but im still a little bit confused because i have a issu with adding your code to my code ;( so could you pls mak a example :D

Comment: I don't have a full (working) example myself. What are your issues?

Comment: i have some trouple with adding your code, but maby you could try :D so it also can be easy for the other people there are reading this :D

Comment: I did. I have added a full working code example that you can copy paste into your form code. It includes VB comments that explains differences from your code. What else do you need? (Note: You will have to add a Label "lblSpeed" to your form in order to display the speed.